# Active Directory and Domain on Azure Standalone machine

Tags: azure, entra-id

Hi serverfault experts,

I'm starting to create a Windows VM on Azure to demonstrate a system running on it. This system does require its machine to be member of a valid Windows Domain (cannot use workgroup). 
Doing that on-premises, I would have to create a Domain Controller and run Active Diretory on it right? But, for Azure, do I have to create another machine to accomplish this task? Isn't there any other Azure that can use this without properly creating another machine just for this case?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deploy a separate VM to use AD services you can leverage the free Azure Active Directory Edition that is included with all subscriptions. You can check [this MS link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/) to confirm it can meet your needs. Azure AD is slightly different from what we are used to on-premises but it can be useful.

Also, look for "Azure Active Directory" in the Azure portal and navigate to the various elements in the blade.

Comment: You need Azure AD DS to join a machine to Azure AD. Azure AD on it's own isn't enough.

Comment: Checking this document, the free tier does support creating users and adding devices to the domain. Does that mean I can add computers to it right? 
Have you already used this Free Azure AD for simple cases like this one? Was this enough?
Thanks! @Humberto Castellon!

Comment: Azure AD Join only allows you to join Windows 10 devices to Azure AD. For everything else you need Azure AD DS.

Comment: @joeqwerty Does that means I must create a new VM to run AD DS pointing to Azure AD? I have a Windows Server 2016 machine there, it's the only machine I did create, is this enough?

Comment: Start here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started

Comment: Then here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal

Answer (score 1):

Azure Active Directory is not the Active Directory you know and (maybe) love. In its default form it doesn't support things like computer domain join, it is really just a user and group store. I've put together a post that describes the different between these two [here](https://samcogan.com/azure-active-directory-is-not-active-directory/).

It is possible to have Azure AD function more like classic AD with a service called Azure AD Domain Services, this will allow you to join machines to it. However, it does have a number of limitations, one of which is that it is going to cost you a minimum of $90-$100 a month, even if you have a very small domain. You are also limited to what rights you have on the domain and what you can do with it.